# adding multiple options in Alert: SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, alert, ios14

[image]
From ios 15 SWiftUI provides an action parameter for adding multiple options in alert, but for lesser OS versions how can we achieve that?

from iOS 15

```
 view.alert("Choose a package", isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Button("Standard") { package = "Standard" }
            Button("Pro") { package = "Pro" }
            Button("Premium") { package = "Premium" }
        }
```

Any native option for iOS 14 or below?

Comment: You have to make custom alerts using `.actionSheet`, `.sheet`, and `.popover`

Comment: @NazmulHasan but i want the same look like alert.